# React - Iterate counter for each component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

This, like every thing, is probably painfully simple. I'm having trouble iterating a count (1, 2, 3, 4, etc up to 50) that I'm passing props to a component:

```
const cards = []

const counter = 0

someData.map(() => {
  cards.push(<SomeCard count1={counter} count2={counter + 1} />)
})
```

It should come out representing something like this (iterating up to 50):

```
<SomeCard count1="0" count2="1" />
<SomeCard count1="1" count2="2" />
<SomeCard count1="2" count2="3" />
<SomeCard count1="3" count2="4" />
<SomeCard count1="4" count2="5" />
```

IE I'd like to iterate "SomeCard" 50 times with "count1" and "count2" climbing in sequence each time.
Any help is thoroughly appreciated!

Comment: What is `someData`? Also, `count1` will only ever be `0` and `count2` will only ever be `1`, because you're never incrementing the value of `counter` (which would need to be declares as a `let` instead of a const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the index in the map callback instead - and don't use `.push`, `.map` is for creating a new array from scratch, not for side-effects.

```
const cards = someData.map((_, i) =>
  <SomeCard count1={i} count2={i + 1} />
)
```

Passing two props when one's data can be completely determined from the other is superfluous though - consider leaving off `count2` entirely, and calculating it inside `SomeCard`.

Comment: I get the error: "ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'cards' before initialization" but I was able to make it work by leaving `const cards = []` and changing your code to `const card...`

Comment: Oops, I said not to `push` but forgot to actually change that in the code

Answer (score 0):

First off, **counter** should not be a constant. (use `let`)

Secondly, you need to increment you **counter** variable. The current configuration does not alter the value of **counter** so it remains the same.
`counter + 1` returns a value to `count2` without changing the value of **counter**!
So basically you need to assign the value to **counter** before you assign to **count2**

```
counter = counter + 1
```

A shorthand for this is `++counter` which you assign directly to **count2**.

So overall, something like this:

```
const cards = []

let counter = 0

someData.map(() => {
  cards.push(<SomeCard count1={counter} count2={++counter} />)
})
```